# Google Play store gift card - not accepting?

Tags: google-play-store

I have born in LocationA, and I have registered an nice gmail email address when I was young in LocationA.

I have moved to LocationB, and bought a new phone in LocationB.

Now, I got a gift card (which shall be redeemed via https://play.google.com/redeem.

However no matter what I do, it keeps telling me:

> Couldn't redeem this code. This code can only be used in LocationB

I'm currently at LocationB. My phone has been bought in LocationB. I just made a mistake that I born in LocationA.

So what now? Come on Google, why are you this stupid?

If I open https://pay.google.com and check my "Addresses", I have only one, guess what: in LocationB.

Everything is in LocationB, and Google's very perfect AI keeps telling me that an error occured as I can only redeem this gift code in LocationB.

It's really a shame. Also, that Google has so smart customer care that it seems much faster and wiser to ask this question from the community, as I can imagine I'm not the only one suffering from this "feature".

Comment: Open the Google Play Store app Google Play.
At the top right, tap the profile icon.
Tap Settings and then General and then Account and device preferences and then Country and profiles. What is the country you see there A or B? Where was the gift card obtained A or B?// gift card can only be redeemed in the country you obtained as per the Play Store country details

Comment: Gift card was bough in LocationB too. Only I born and register gmail in LocationA 10+ years earlier. Profile icon doesn't have "Settings". It has only "Google Account". But "Google Account" doesn't have Device preferences. It has "Home", "Personal Info", "Data and privacy", "Security", "People and sharing", "Payments and subscriptions"

Comment: [How to change your Google Play country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

Comment: If your email in Play Store is associated with country A, you need to change the Google Play country. I was about to link that and @Robert already did that

Comment: Robert: Payments profile / Country/Region in "pay.google.com" shows LocationB. Also on the same page, "Name and address" shows LocationB. Just I went to see my parents in summer, and came back yesterday if that matters. Silly silly google

Comment: See the section [Problems with Play country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3422659?hl=en#zippy=%2Cproblems-with-play-country%2Cpurchased-an-item-with-a-different-account%2Ccant-redeem-your-code%2Credeem-when-making-a-purchase-on-google-play)

Comment: Where did you got the gift card from? May be the card was bought in the "wrong country"?

Comment: Thank you, all are true. I'm resident, country display labels are everywhere "LocationB", I have just got the gift card which was bought in LocationB, and I'm physically located at LocationB. Google MUST know this as I got an email confirmation with flight ticket, so there it is an open secret in front of their eyes. How much I hate them OMG

Comment: Guys. Nothing is different. Everywhere in Google there is only "LocationB" printed. Everywhere. Okay, 17yrs ago I have registered my Google Account in another country, but currently, that country is nowhere listed/printed/marked/shown.

Comment: Again, what is the location in your Play Store as per my first comment?

Comment: B. The country where I'm currently located. Which is also the same where we have bought this shitty gift card.

Comment: In which case you can either reach out to Google [support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/?hl=en#topic=3364260) or request for refund (see link I posted earlier) and post your answer here to help others

Comment: One remote possibility is that Google thinks you are in country A, since you came back yesterday only. Clear the cache of Play Store app and restart your device and try

Comment: Tried all of them. Even reinstalled the Play store, nothing helped.

Comment: Only solution seem to completely keep yourself away from *Goolge* products, and switch to Apple.

Comment: Haha, even google can't solve this :D. They told me 25hours ago that they have a solid maximal 24hours to reply to my email: no emails has been received. Perhaps Gmail is also buggy. But for sure, their support is 0/10. One of worse CC in the whole world.

Answer (score 1):

Google fixed this after more than a week.

They haven't give me any reason or root cause, nor any possible steps to avoid this in the future.

Congrats.